# How to set a variable of type number without a value

Tags: typescript

I have a simple Vue app where I set the index of a loop on a value in the component:

```
export default class MovieSearchResultList extends Vue {
  imagePath = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w45';

  public hover = -1;

  public hoverEvent(index: number) {
    this.hover = index;
  }
}

<template>
  <ul id='movieSearchResultList'>
    <li
      v-for='(movie, index) in searchList'
      v-on:mouseover='hoverEvent(index)'
      v-on:mouseout='hoverEvent()'
      :key='movie.id'>
      <AddMovieToDashboard v-if='hover === index' />
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

I don't like that I have to initiate the `public hover` on a value of `-1`, 0 would be the first element in the list.

If I create the hover var like this:

```
public hover: number;
```

I get:

> Property 'hover' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can denote that it can also be `undefined` (or perhaps another value if you'd prefer).

Example using `undefined`:

```js
public hover: number | undefined;
```

Example using another value (eg: `null`):

```js
public hover: number | null = null;
```